# Woocommerce rest api error saying There has been a critical error on this website

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

When we hit the Woocommerce api in wp it gives error as

> There has been a critical error on this website.

but our website is running and there is no error but its giving so. Here is the screenshot: [image]

Comment: make wp_debug as true in wp_config.php & check what's the error

Comment: it has caused because of woo commerce recommendation plugin error.solved now